# 400 Bad Request When Using Boto

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I'm following the basic boto tutorial to try to connect to an EC2 instance. When I tried to create a simple instance to a basic Amazon Linux AMI, I got the following error:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
conn.run_instances('ami-1ecae776')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 973, in run_instances
    verb='POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1208, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

`InvalidParameterCombination`Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type.fb016420-47f3-4453-b0bc-ebd2f3c70ba5

I apologize if this has been addressed elsewhere in SO but I really did a thorough search, including trying the answers in [400 Bad Request while pulling instances with amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070259/400-bad-request-while-pulling-instances-with-amazon). The date command on my machine and date on the remote aws servers seem to match so I'm not sure what could be causing this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you have specified is the AMI.  That particular AMI is HVM-based and will work with all current generation EC2 instance types.  However, the default value for `instance_type` in boto is `m1.small` and that older-generation instance type only supports PV virtualization.

So, to get your command running, you need to explicitly specify the `instance_type` parameter, like this:

```
conn.run_instances('ami-1ecae776', instance_type='t1.micro')
```

In addition to `instance_type`, you probably also want to provide a few other parameters in your call such as `key_name`, and `security_groups`.  Otherwise, you won't be able to log into your instance.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I tried adding that information and still got the issue. I was able to get around the issue by using a more recent AMI.